# Load html content in DIV on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with many divs on that use tabs:

```
<div class="tab-box">
    <a href="#companyinfo" class="tabLink activeLink">Company</a> 
    <a href="#contacts" class="tabLink">Contacts</a>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="companyinfo">
content 1
</div>

<div class="tabcontent hide" id="contacts">
content 2
</div>
```

how can i only load each div when the tab has been clicked?

i thought about doing this:

```
function LoadDivPage(pagename, divname) {
    var page = pagename
    $('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $(divname).load(page, function(){
         //new html exists now 
        $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}

<a href="#contacts" class="tabLink" onclick="LoadDivPage('http://www.google.co.uk/', '#contacts');">Contacts</a>
```

but its not loading google.co.uk and im not sure this is the best way

Comment: Try this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: you can't do that( particularly *loading google into a div* ) unless the request has the same origin. ( or server is configured to allow cross origin requests ). See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by loading the content only if the target div is not available:

```
$(function(){
    var LoadDivPage = function(pagename, divname) {
        var page = pagename,
            containerClass = 'container-'+divname,
            container = $('<div/>').addClass( containerClass );

        if( $('.'+containerClass).length > 0 ) return;

        $('#LoadingDiv').show();

        $.get(page, function(data){
            container.html(data).appendTo( $(divname) );
            $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
        });
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }

    $('.tabLink').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).data('page'),
            div = $(this).attr('href');

        LoadDivPage(page, div);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ag901f8m/2/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.tabLink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabLink').addClass('activeLink').not(this).removeClass('activeLink');
    $('.tabcontent').addClass('hide');

    //Id of current tabcontent
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(currentTab).removeClass('hide');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/696rdvzb/)

Comment: this doesnt load the actual content onclick though

Comment: it displays div with id equal to href value of clicked element